# Count number on values (which are measure) in a table

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

I have a table which is the **monthly average** of a group of data, and at the same time is the hourly average of that month.

| Month | Hour | AVE Value1 | Measure_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 0 | -5.0 |  |
| January | 1 | -5.0 |  |
| January | 2 | -5.0 |  |
| January | 3 | 16 | 2% |
| January | 4 | 50 | 1.5% |
| January | 5 | 150 | 3% |
| January | 6 | 50 | 0.4% |
| January | 7 | 10 | 1.4% |
| January | 8 | -5.0 |  |
| January | 9 | -5.0 |  |
| January | 10 | -5.0 |  |

And I would like to add a column which count each value in my Measure_1 column **in this table**.

```
Measure_2 = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTAX('Fact Table_DATE', [Measure_1]),
    FILTER('Fact Table_TIME', [Hour]),
    FILTER('Fact Table_DATE', [Month])
)
```

Because what I am having is the count of values of the raw data which I use it to construct this average table.

What I have:

| Month | Hour | AVE Value1 | Measure_1 | Measure_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 0 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 1 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 2 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 3 | 16 | 2% | 31 |
| January | 4 | 50 | 1.5% | 31 |
| January | 5 | 150 | 3% | 31 |
| January | 6 | 50 | 0.4% | 31 |
| January | 7 | 10 | 1.4% | 31 |
| January | 8 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 9 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 10 | -5.0 |  |  |

That 31 represent the numbers of days in January and which has a value as I mention.

What I want:

| Month | Hour | AVE Value1 | Measure_1 | Measure_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| January | 0 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 1 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 2 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 3 | 16 | 2% | 1 |
| January | 4 | 50 | 1.5% | 1 |
| January | 5 | 150 | 3% | 1 |
| January | 6 | 50 | 0.4% | 1 |
| January | 7 | 10 | 1.4% | 1 |
| January | 8 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 9 | -5.0 |  |  |
| January | 10 | -5.0 |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Measure_2 = 
COUNTX(
    SUMMARIZE(
         'Fact Table_TIME', 
          'Fact Table_TIME'[Hour]
    ), 
    [Measure_1] 
)
```

I asked in another [forum](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Count-number-on-values-which-are-measure-in-a-table/m-p/3145430#M112506) and the solution it is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "allexcept" formula replace "filter"

see as attached image [measure_2]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't see the “image”, but I change the AllEXCEPT function and I got a different value. Instead of the 31, 31, 31, 31, 31 I have 1, 2, 2, 2. 2. Do you know why it is happening like that?

Comment: try formula below:

Measure_2 = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTAX('Fact Table_DATE', [Measure_1]),
    ALLEXCEPT('Fact Table_DATE','Fact Table_DATE'[Month],'Fact Table_DATE'[Hour])
)